# Why does Control have the Controls property, if not all extensions of may have children?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, controls

I am building a custom `Control`, which also has a custom  `ControlCollection`, which in theory should only have to contain child `Control` objects of a specific subtype. My implementation is similar to this:

```
public class CustomControl : Control {
  private SpecificInformationContainer components;

  public class CustomControlCollection : ControlCollection {
    public CustomControlCollection(CustomControl owner) : base(owner) {
      foreach (var info in owner.components) {
          base.Add(new SpecificChildControl(info));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover, the child `Control` shouldn't have to be directly added through the `Controls` property of the parent.

But this predicament has shed a light on something that has been bugging me since: *Why does the base class* `Control` *even assume all of its extensions to have children, when in actuality for many of them it doesn't even make sense? (e.g.* `Button`*)*

Comment: Winforms is a wrapper around Windows own UI. And in that system every window/control can have a parent and that is just replicated here (just turned logically around from a parent to a childs dependency). And actually you can show other controls on a button or any other control. Try a `myLovelyButton.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Hello" });` and see yourself. It may not make sense to you (or me) but someone somewhere may have found a use for it.

Comment: You may try hiding that Property with a `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` Attribute. That is what other Controls also do to hide for example the Text Property. Since every Control has a Text Property but not with all it makes sense or is even shown.

Comment: It is part of the constructor and needs to be run when a control does have children.

Comment: @Ralf Very interesting, because in Design Mode the `Button` will never be given the child `Control`. I will also be looking into this attribute. Thank you!